# "The operation could not be completed" Error when saving a file, in many projects

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

I am getting this annoying problem, whenever i do some changes to any file in any of my many projects and try to save the file, i get the error "The operation could not be completed"!!!!

it only has an "OK" button, clicking that button will open a "Save As" dialog to save the file into a different location.

most of the time, after trying with different approaches (click CTRL+S, open File-> Save, open File-> Save All, or closing the windows and clicking "Save" when being asked to save), it works, but usually that takes 2-3 tries in average per change (a developer has a finger glued to CTRL+S).

i disabled all add ins, actually i only have JustCode. i restarted the machine, nothing worked.

anyone can help please?
BTW: i have VS.NET 2005 Team Suite SP2, Windows 7 Ultimate,  and the problem happens in all types of projects (WEB, Windows Service, SQL, anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution
It was my anti-virus, once i excluded the project folder from the control of the anti-virus everything is fine now.